# How to open PDF as BASH variable?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, command-line, bash

I'm trying to open a PDF using Preview where the input file is a shell var:

```
$ pdf=$(wget -qO- 'http://website.com/file.pdf') && open "$pdf"

$ pdf=$(wget -qO- 'http://website.com/file.pdf') && open -a /Applications/Preview.app -f "$pdf"

$ open -a /Applications/Preview.app $(wget -qO- 'http://website.com/file.pdf')

$ pdf=$(wget -qO- 'http://website.com/file.pdf') | open -a /Applications/Preview.app -f -
```

etc etc etc

I always get the same error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/open: Argument list too long

Is it possible to do this?

example PDF for anyone who wants to try:

https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/english/44592-linux-restricted-shell-bypass-guide.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool problem showing how amazing bash, pipes and open are. You are *so close* on the fourth try:

```
wget -qO- 'https://www.com/big.pdf' | open -f -a Preview.app
```

Luckily the `-a` argument lets the `-f` take the data from stdin but not open in TextEdit.

Comment: Right back at you, @lily - I had fun trying lots of half efforts before checking the man page and hoping the two options would work.

Comment: This answer isn't complete, the question refers specifically to opening a PDF using Preview where the input file is a shell var.

Comment: I'm really impressed -- I would not have expected this to work, but it does!

Answer (score 1):

You can open a PDF as a Bash variable (expressed as a path to the file) like this.

1. Set your variable:

   ```
   pdf=/path/to/44592-linux-restricted-shell-bypass-guide.pdf
   ```
2. Open the file like this:

   ```
   open "$pdf" -a Preview
   ```

However, your example indicates that the file doesn't exist on your filesystem. If you want to open a raw data stream stored in a variable, I recommend echoing your variable, and piping it to `open` using the `-f` option like this.

1. Define your variable:

   ```
   pdf=$(wget -qO- https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/english/44592-linux-restricted-shell-bypass-guide.pdf)
   ```
2. Open the raw data as a stream from standard input:

   ```
   echo $pdf | open -f -a Preview
   ```

Explanation:
If you store the output of `wget -qO- …` as a variable, as opposed to downloading the file onto your filesystem, `open` won't know what to do as you're passing it the raw file data rather than the path to the file. In `man open` ‘file’ refers to an openable file for the given application, the variable in your example is not that. The `-f` option is useful in this scenario as your method of setting the variable involves storing the entire file stream, which won't be interpreted as a file by `open`, and therefore it can only be opened as a file stream.

Comment: This won't work because it will corrupt the file in several ways. First, variables are not suitable for binary data, especially anything that contains null characters (zero bytes). Second, using a variable reference without double-quotes around it will subject the value to word splitting and wildcard expansion. Finally, `echo` adds a newline to the end of what it print. You can solve the last two problems using `printf "%s" "$pdf"` instead of `echo $pdf`, but the first is harder to solve. You'd have to do something like storing it in base64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Gordon. I did _not_ know that about variables and null data. So effectively what the question is originally trying to achieve isn't possible?

Comment: I should mention though, that this code does indeed run successfully for this example.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing @bmike suggested but without `wget` which isn't native to OS X

```sh
curl -so- 'https://www.example.com/some.pdf' | open -f -a Preview.app
```